# Bash count non-commented lines and write to output with filename

Tags: bash

I would like to count the non-commented lines in multiple files and append the result to an output file

This is how I would count the non-commented lines for multiple files, but I don't know how to store the result together with the filename in an output.txt file.

```
for file in *txt
do
  cat "$file" | sed '/^\s*#/d' | wc -l
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write several things per line, and you can redirect the output of the whole loop to a file:

```
for file in *txt
do
  echo -n $file' '
  cat "$file" | sed '/^\s*#/d' | wc -l
done > output.txt
```

Also you can shorten the file processing down to:

```
egrep -v '^\s*#' "$file" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *txt
do
  cat "$file" | sed '/^\s*#/d' | wc -l >> output.txt
done
```